How to increase gas limit for transactions in Foundry?
Is there a way to do it in the script file itself or through terminal command?
Currently making transactions using the command:
forge script script/Counter.s.sol:CounterScript --rpc-url $SEPOLIA_RPC_URL --broadcast

The Counter script is just doing a simple function call:
bool success = ver.verify_bls(signature, publicKeys, messages);


You can specify the gas limit for your particular function call / transaction in your script, by changing your function call from:
bool success = ver.verify_bls(signature, publicKeys, messages);

to using .call:
(bool success, bytes memory returnData) = address(ver).call{gas: 3_000_000}(abi.encodeWithSelector(ver.verify_bls.selector, signature, publicKeys, messages));
if (success) {
   // Decode the return data to a boolean
   bool result = abi.decode(returnData, (bool));
}

So, in this, you can replace 3_000_000 with the appropriate gas limit as per your use case.
